# How can i extract words from a single concatenated word?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, word-embeddings, bert, spacy

I'm stuck on this problem and would love some input.

I have mulitple words such as *getExtention*, *getPath*, *someWord* or *someword* and i want to separate each concatinated words into its own words such as:

getExtention ---> [get][Extention].

someword --> [some][word].

The concatenated words can also be in all small letters.

Do you guys have any ideas how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use a package that relies on a spellchecker to find the best way to split, like this one: https://pypi.org/project/compound-word-splitter/

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the tip